# Memory stream is not expandable when I send a object to Server side from Client

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I have "Memory not expandable" issue when I try to send serialized object to server I do not understand why, my buffer have a size of 1024 bytes but I send only a object with total of 24 bytes . Serialization increase size of object ??

I have no idea so I have not tried anything particular, apart from looking on the forum topics that are related to my problem.

```cs
    private const int BYTE_SIZE = 1024;
```

send function :

```cs
 public void sendToServer(NMSG msg, int channelId)
    {

        if (!PacketHandler.packets.Contains(msg.GetType()))
        {
            Debug.Log("packet not registered");
            return;
        }

        byte error;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        formatter.Serialize(ms, msg); //error occur here.

        int bufferSize = BYTE_SIZE;
        NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
    }
```

sended object:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class NMSG_CreatePlayer : NMSG
{

    public string playerName;

    public float? posX;
    public float? posY;

    public int? shipSlot;
    public int? skinSlot;
    public int? particleSlot;
    public int? trailSlot1;
    public int? trailSlot2;
    public int? connectionId;


    public NMSG_CreatePlayer(string playerName) : base((byte)PacketHandler.packets.IndexOf(typeof(NMSG_CreatePlayer)))
    {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public NMSG_CreatePlayer(string playerName, int connectionId, float posX, float posY, int shipSlot, int skinSlot, int particleSlot, int trailSlot1, int trailSlot2) : base((byte)PacketHandler.packets.IndexOf(typeof(NMSG_CreatePlayer)))
    {
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.shipSlot = shipSlot;
        this.skinSlot = skinSlot;
        this.particleSlot = particleSlot;
        this.trailSlot1 = trailSlot1;
        this.trailSlot2 = trailSlot2;
        this.connectionId = connectionId;
    }

    //Here packet data send from server
    public override void HandleClient(NMSG msg)
    {
        NMSG_CreatePlayer cmsg = (NMSG_CreatePlayer)msg;
        Player p = new Player(cmsg.playerName,0);
        Ship ship = (Ship)Item.getItemById((int)cmsg.shipSlot);
        Skin skin = (Skin)Item.getItemById((int)cmsg.skinSlot);
        Particle particle = (Particle)Item.getItemById((int) this.particleSlot);
        Trail trail1 = (Trail)Item.getItemById((int) this.trailSlot1);
        Trail trail2 = (Trail)Item.getItemById((int) this.trailSlot2);

        GameObject instance = GameObject.Instantiate(trail2 != null ? Main.instance.modelInitializator.playerModel_2Trail : Main.instance.modelInitializator.playerModel_1Trail, GameObject.Find("World").transform);

        p.setPosition((float)cmsg.posX, (float)cmsg.posY);
        instance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(p.getPositionX(),p.getPositionY(), 0);
        instance.name = playerName;

        p.setObject(instance);
        p.applyEquipment(ship, skin, particle, trail1, trail2);
        p.setName(playerName);
        p.setConnectionId((int)connectionId);

        instance.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Client.getClient().players.Add((int)connectionId, p);

        if ((int) connectionId == Client.getClient().getConnectionId())
        {
            instance.AddComponent<PlayerController>();
            Main.player = p;
            Client.getClient().gm = GameManager.createGameManager(p);
            p.isInGame = true;
        }
    }

    //Here packet data send from client
    public override void HandleServer(NMSG msg, int connectionId)
    {
        NMSG_CreatePlayer cmsg = (NMSG_CreatePlayer)msg;
        Player p = Server.getPlayer(connectionId);
        p.setName(cmsg.playerName);
        float posx = World.generateRandomPosX();
        float posy = World.generateRandomPosY();
        p.setPosition(posx, posy);

        GameObject instance = GameObject.Instantiate(Main.instance.modelInitializator.player, GameObject.Find("World").transform);
        instance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posx, posy, 0);

        p.playerGameObject = instance;

        int shipSlot = p.pData.shipSlot == null ? 0 : p.pData.shipSlot.getItemId();
        int skinSlot = p.pData.skinSlot == null ? 0 : p.pData.skinSlot.getItemId();
        int particleSlot = p.pData.particleSlot == null ? 0 : p.pData.particleSlot.getItemId();
        int trailSlot1 = p.pData.trailSlot1 == null ? 0 : p.pData.trailSlot1.getItemId();
        int trailSlot2 = p.pData.trailSlot2 == null ? 0 : p.pData.trailSlot2.getItemId();
        Server.getServer().sendToAll(new NMSG_CreatePlayer(p.getName(), p.getConnectionId(), p.getPositionX(), p.getPositionY(), shipSlot, skinSlot, particleSlot, trailSlot1, trailSlot2),Server.getServer().reliableChannel);
        p.isInGame = true;
    }


}

}
```

NMSG class :

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class NMSG
{

    private byte? discriminator = null;
    public NMSG(byte discriminator) { this.discriminator = discriminator; }

    public byte? getPacketId()
    {
        return this.discriminator;
    }

    public abstract void HandleServer(NMSG msg, int connectionId);

    public abstract void HandleClient(NMSG msg);

}
```

I'm totally lost...
I waiting impatiently your helps thanks.

Comment: What is `BYTE_SIZE`? Is it 24? You probably want `new MemoryStream()`, then `ms.ToArray()` (or `ms.Length` combined with `ms.GetBuffer()`)

Comment: BYTE_SIZE value is 1024 I don't understand why I get "Memory is not expandable" error , I send only data which contains 24 byte ...

Comment: What is `NMSG`?

Comment: NMSG is a custom abstract class that I created for serialize and send over network

Comment: Put in in your question, please, so we can see how big it is.

Comment: here I have just done it.

Answer (score 1):

That type requires at least 1165 bytes for the BinarySerializer.
So you need to make BYTE_SIZE bigger, or let your MemoryStream auto-grow.

Here's a repro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp25
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class NMSG_CreatePlayer : NMSG
    {
        public NMSG_CreatePlayer() : base(0)
        { }
        public string playerName;

        public float? posX;
        public float? posY;

        public int? shipSlot;
        public int? skinSlot;
        public int? particleSlot;
        public int? trailSlot1;
        public int? trailSlot2;
        public int? connectionId;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public abstract class NMSG
    {

        private byte? discriminator = null;
        public NMSG(byte discriminator) { this.discriminator = discriminator; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        public static void sendToServer(NMSG msg, int channelId)
        {

            int BYTE_SIZE = 1024;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            formatter.Serialize(ms, msg);
            Console.WriteLine(ms.Position);


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var o = new NMSG_CreatePlayer();
            sendToServer(o, 0);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cant repro" means that it works fine. And the code you posted isn't the cause of your error.

Comment: Ok I see , I'm really sorry it's the bad class I just updated it now NMSG_CreatePlayer and according to Unity console the error come in same line.

Comment: That class has a BinarySerializer size of 1165, larger than your fixed-size MemoryStream.

Comment: Ok I see how are you doing to have size? and what makes the size so big?

Comment: how to make sure to remove these metadata do you have a link that explains this clearly? because I think it takes up too much space.

Comment: @NEOX You can write a custom serializer to avoid storing that metadata. You can also try serializing your data as JSON - the raw data would likely be less than 1024 bytes.

Comment: @xxbbcc I understand better thanks to you , I think that my problem is solved thank you.